# ExtJs changing layout of formpanel buttons

Tags: button, extjs, javascript, extjs3, formpanel

I have a formpanel

```
var form = new Ext.form.FormPanel({
    title: 'Form Layout',

    buttons: [
        {text: 'Save'},
        {text: 'Cancel'}
    ]

});
```

I want to change the layout of the buttons below, so that they appear one below the other.
Can I assign a layout to these buttons or is there another way?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
var form = new Ext.form.FormPanel({
title: 'Form Layout',

buttons: [{

    xtype: 'panel', 
    items: [
      {text: 'Save'},
      {text: 'Cancel'}
    ]
 }]
```

});

this helps, but maybe its not a proper solution till i find a real one. marking for now, will change later when a better one arrives

Answer (score 1):

Instead of adding as buttons you can go for items into fbar of this form panel , and add each button component here

Comment: yes, that also works, i found another solution, also note that buttons config overrides the fbar.